# Error "fileid changed" when accessing files over NFS

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

I have an nfs-kernel-server configured and running on Ubuntu 10.04 Server.

```
/export THIRD_SERVER_IP(rw,fsid=0,insecure,no_subtree_check,async) SECOND_SERVER_IP(rw,fsid=0,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
/export/ebs THIRD_SERVER_IP(rw,fsid=0,insecure,no_subtree_check,async) SECOND_SERVER_IP(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

I mounted the exported folder to the second server:

```
mount -t nfs4 -o proto=tcp,port=2049 NFS_SERVER_IP_HERE:/ebs /ebs
```

and it works just fine. I mounted it to the third server but I cannot access files from it.

```
ls -l /ebs
ls: reading directory /ebs: Stale NFS file handle
total 0
```

The syslog on the third server says:

```
kernel: [11575.483720] NFS: server NFS_SERVER_IP_HERE error: fileid changed
kernel: [11575.483722] fsid 0:14: expected fileid 0x2, got 0x6e001
```

Some info:

```
uname -r
2.6.32-312-ec2
uname -m
i686
```

Comment: Found an answer. Cannot post it now because of 24hours limit.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I marked all answered questions as Answered.

Answer (score 3):

The error happened because of wrong **fsid** value in /etc/exports.

I replaced the second line with this one:

```
/export/ebs THIRD_SERVER_IP(rw,insecure,no_subtree_check,async) SECOND_SERVER_IP(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

and now it works.

Comment: Please accept your own answer if you found the solution to your problem!